# Installing texlive on sd card in a Chromebook

Tags: texlive, linux, debian

In a Chromebook we can activate developer mode which installs a virtual machine and then we can run debain in it. Most of the Chromebooks have limited storage. I am using a cheap Lenovo Chromebook which has only 64GB of internal storage. Fortunately it has a microsd card slot. So I bought a 128GB sd card and I keep this card permanently attached to my Chromebook.

In a Chromebook we can share the whole card or a folder in this card with the virtual machine running debian. This shared folder can then be accessed as a subfolder of /mnt/chromeos directory. I want to install a full texlive installation using tl-install. But, I want it to use a folder in sd card for installation instead of internal storage.

The biggest issue that I am facing is that it fails to install various packages. It fails to create symlinks to various files in scripts directory.

I am new to linux and command line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What has your question to do with LaTeX and friends?

Comment: what is your question? The installer asks for a location directory and you can specify one on your sd card, there should be nothing special to do apart from that

Comment: @David Carlisle I have updated the question.

Comment: the advice (always) is not to create symlinks, just unpack texlive into (any) directory, so on your card in this case, then set PATH to include the texlive  bin directory just created and then you are done, there is nothing different about the filesystem being on a card.

Comment: you say "it" failed to install, but have not said what "it" is, note you do not want to install debian texlive using apt as that will install in the system directories, install texlive from tug https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html